# Proxy my Elastic Search connection through Django for filtering

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I believe I need to proxy my ElasticSearch connection via a Django URL in order to do filtering by user token.

So instead of going via `localhost:9200/_search`, I want to use `localhost:8000/myapi/elastic/_search`.

I am unsure how to connect them. I've tried using a serializers/views setup

## myapp/search.py

```
class TaskIndex(DocType):
    title = String()
    class Meta:
        index = 'task-index'

# Bulk indexing function, run in shell
def bulk_indexing():
    TaskIndex.init()
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Task.objects.all().iterator()))

# Simple search function
def _search(title):
    s = Search().filter('term', title=title.text)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

## api/serializers.py

from myapp.search import TaskIndex

```
class ElasticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskIndex
```

## api/views.py

```
class ElasticViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TaskIndex.objects.none()
    serializer_class = ElasticSerializer
```

## api/urls.py

```
router.register(r'elastic', ElasticViewSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I was able to achieve it. Really simple method:

## views.py

```
from services import elastic_result

class ElasticView(APIView):
    permission_classes=[]
    def post(self, title):
        _search = elastic_result(id, title)
        return _search
        pass
```

## services.py

```
import requests
import json

def elastic_result(id, request):
    requestdata = json.loads(request.body)
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/_search', json=requestdata)
    items = r.json()
    return Response(items)
```

## urls.py

```
import ElasticView
url(r'^elastic/_search', ElasticView.as_view()
```